# Google Cloud SQL VM refusing connection

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I have been stuck trying to figure out why my Cloud SQL VM is refusing my connection from my machine (whom ip address I have added as a subnet). I cann SSH into the VM but i cannot access the VM from a browser to make SQLs. I have scoured the internet for days trying to find a fix but i cannot seem to get pass this point. My apache listens to port 80. Also Id like to add that I have been connecting to my Mysql db for months through php and making sqls so I do not believe the problem is with apache. However if it is please point me to where i should be looking.

Comment: Can you explain your setup in a little more detail? Google Cloud SQL provides only a 3306 endpoint so there is no way to SSH to that IP.

Comment: There is an option on the console to a.) SSH via your terminal or b.) SSH via your browser.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have MySQL running on a GCE VM, *not* an actual CloudSQL instance (that is a different service from GCE).  Is that right?

If so, then if you are trying to connect from your local machine directly to the mysql instance, you are probably getting blocked by the firewall.  Go to the networks tab (under Compute Engine) on the cloud console and see what firewall rules you have enabled.  You might need to add one for 3306 or whatever port you are using.